# "arriving at length of" meaning?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

"... organisms evolved within and satisfactorily fitting their communities, arriving at length of beauty and goodness, it is difficult to say where the natural facts leave off and where the natural values appear"

Can someone clarify the expression "arriving at lenght of beauty and goodness"? Specifically, I'm confused by the use of the preposition "of". I am assuming the meaning is "arriving in the end/finally at beauty and goodness". I've never heard the expression "arriving at length of" before (I'm not a native speaker). Is it commonly used or is this a typo? What is the logic behind calling it a 'length of beauty'? Thank you.

Comment: Could you tell us the source of the quotation? It looks like a typo to me.  This seems to be the original source: https://books.google.com/books?id=KEw_xlyJukMC&pg=PA232&lpg=PA232&dq=organisms+evolved+within+and+satisfactorily+fitting+their+communities,+arriving+at+length+of+beauty+and+goodness&source=bl&ots=ersw4d0tgH&sig=ACfU3U1urw6B8VNJqxkwawizhLt_om8_Tg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJ-JO9gbrkAhW9FzQIHVa7CSMQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=organisms%20evolved%20within%20and%20satisfactorily%20fitting%20their%20communities%2C%20arriving%20at%20length%20of%20beauty%20and%20goodness&f=false

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, I'm a native speaker and, so far as I know "at length" means "eventually" so "arriving at length of beauty and goodness" makes very little sense to me. Replacing "at length" with "eventually" gives "arriving eventually of beauty and goodness" which definitely makes no sense. I think it's a typo.

Comment: No idea (native speaker too), unless there's a typo and it should be arriving *at length* at beauty and goodnes.